# How do I get the points of each word?

Tags: python

I'm making a program that could count the points of two or more words. How do I get the value of each point in a list in an array? I already have a dictionary of points.

```
points_dictionary = {
        'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3,
        'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 4, 'G': 2,
        'H': 4, 'I': 1, 'J': 8, 'K': 5,
        'L': 1, 'M': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 1,
        'P': 3, 'Q': 10, 'R': 1, 'S': 1,
        'T': 1, 'U': 1, 'V': 4, 'W': 4, 'X': 8,
        'Y': 4, 'Z': 10, '#': 0, '0':3
    }
```

I have a list that looks like this`currwords = ['PEARS' 'MANGO' 'ORANGE]`
I have made a code that can get the points of each letter but its output adds all the points.

```
for you in currwords:
    for yeah in you:
        trans = list(yeah)
        trans = points_dictionary[yeah[0]]
        total_words.append(trans)
        final1 = sum(total_words)
        print(final1)
```

Every time I use this code it only outputs the total points on what is on the list. How do I get the points specifically on each word like PEAR = 6 MANGO = 8 and ORANGE = 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it ***the old school*** way:

```
points_dictionary = {
        'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3,
        'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 4, 'G': 2,
        'H': 4, 'I': 1, 'J': 8, 'K': 5,
        'L': 1, 'M': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 1,
        'P': 3, 'Q': 10, 'R': 1, 'S': 1,
        'T': 1, 'U': 1, 'V': 4, 'W': 4, 'X': 8,
        'Y': 4, 'Z': 10, '#': 0, '0':3
    }

currwords = ['PEARS', 'MANGO', 'ORANGE']
sumsOfwords = []
sum = 0
i = -1
for words in currwords:
    for word in words:
        if words == currwords[i + 1]:
            sum = sum + points_dictionary[word]
        else:
            sumsOfwords.append(sum)
            sum = 0
            sum = sum + points_dictionary[word]
            i = i + 1

sumsOfwords.append(sum)
print(sumsOfwords)
```

OUTPUT:

> [7, 8, 7]

```
dictionary = dict(zip(currwords, sumsOfwords))
print(dictionary)
```

OUTPUT:

> {'PEARS': 7, 'MANGO': 8, 'ORANGE': 7}

Comment: Thank you!! I also like the old school way.

Comment: @Ash, you may mark the answer that helped you in solving your problem better! cheers ;-)

Comment: Can you explain this part? dictionary = dict(zip(currwords, sumsOfwords)). What is the use of dict and zip?

Comment: @Ash The purpose of `zip()` is to map the similar index of multiple containers so that they can be used just using as single entity. and once done, you may convert it into a dictionary or a list as preferred!

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) together with [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
points_dictionary = {
        'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3,
        'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 4, 'G': 2,
        'H': 4, 'I': 1, 'J': 8, 'K': 5,
        'L': 1, 'M': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 1,
        'P': 3, 'Q': 10, 'R': 1, 'S': 1,
        'T': 1, 'U': 1, 'V': 4, 'W': 4, 'X': 8,
        'Y': 4, 'Z': 10, '#': 0, '0':3
    }

currwords = ['PEARS', 'MANGO', 'ORANGE']

for word in currwords:
    print(word, sum(map(lambda c: points_dictionary.get(c, 0), word)))
```

**Output**

```
PEARS 7
MANGO 8
ORANGE 7
```

As an alternative you could use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
for word in currwords:
    print(word, sum(points_dictionary.get(c, 0) for c in word))
```

The idea of both map and the generator expression is to *map* the letters of each word to the corresponding point values.

Comment: Thank you so much!!. Can you explain too me the use of map and generator expression? It will really much help me understand more! Thank you

Comment: @Ash updated the answer, I think you can take a look to the linked documentations to know more about map and generator expressions.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you append trans to total_words at each iteration, but never reset its value. You could add a

```
total_words = []
```

inside of the first loop. Also, inside of your `for yeah in you` loop, you define trans twice, so the first one is never used. After correcting that, your code should look like this :

```
for you in currwords:
    total_words = []
    for yeah in you:
        trans = points_dictionary[yeah]
        total_words.append(trans)
        final1 = sum(total_words)
        print(final1)
```